# How can I upgrade from Play 2.1.5 to Play 2.2.0?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using the play framework 2.1.5 and now I want to update to 2.2.0,
my operation is:

1. download the 2.2.0 framework from the official site.
2. config the play home to PATH
3. addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
4. update the sbt.version=0.12.2  to sbt.version=0.13.0
5. cd into the project fold and run the commond play compile

It says:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe.play.extras#iteratees-extras_2.10;1.0.1!iteratees-extras_
2.10.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.axis#axis;1.4!axis.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.axis#axis-jaxrpc;1.4!axis-jaxrpc.jar
[error] download failed: commons-discovery#commons-discovery;0.5!commons-discovery.jar
[error] download failed: wsdl4j#wsdl4j;1.6.2!wsdl4j.jar
[error] download failed: dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1!dom4j.jar
[error] download failed: jaxen#jaxen;1.1.4!jaxen.jar
[error] download failed: javax.mail#mail;1.4.5!mail.jar
[error] download failed: javax.activation#activation;1.1!activation.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml;3.6!poi-ooxml.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.poi#poi;3.6!poi.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml-schemas;3.6!poi-ooxml-schemas.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.xmlbeans#xmlbeans;2.3.0!xmlbeans.jar
[error] download failed: stax#stax-api;1.0.1!stax-api.jar
[error] download failed: org.apache.geronimo.specs#geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec;1.0!geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec.jar
[error] download failed: ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1!logback-classic.jar
[error] download failed: ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.1!logback-core.jar
[error] download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.6!slf4j-api.jar
[error] download failed: joda-time#joda-time-hibernate;1.3!joda-time-hibernate.jar
[error] Total time: 1772 s, completed 2014-6-24 20:42:49
```

I saw the file Build.scala in the play framework 2.2.0 is build.sbt.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running `clean` from the play console? Also, this should be in your plugins.sbt: `resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`

Comment: I did that, and another question: I saw the jar references are in the play frameowrk 2.1.5 home , but I'm building using the play 2.2.0, so this will conflict with the old version(play 2.1.5),  how to change the jar reference path to the play 2.2.0 home?